# Export content type in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, import, drupal-7, export, content-type

Is there a way to export a content type from a site and import it to another? I haven't found any modules to do that yet.

How would you achieve that? It's a useful thing to be done otherwise it is very time consuming to create the same content type over and over again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module can export content types and allow you to import into another Drupal site.

Comment: FYI, bundle_copy seems better. It adds an "Export" option under Structure->Content Types - very intuitive to use.

Answer (score 17):

Try [bundle_copy](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy)

It's like the old D6 content copy. For me its quicker.

Comment: Fast and excellent solution for easy copy and update of content types. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: Is there any way to run the code you get in a module in e.g. hook_install()?

Comment: There is a function in the bundle_copy module - bundle_copy_import_submit() with some code that can be using to read the $data array and import in a hook_install...

Answer (score 5):

For options, please see the discussion over at http://drupal.org/node/1011620.  There's also a simple copy/paste module available if Features is too cumbersome for your specific purposes: [Bundle copy](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy).

Answer (score 5):

[Bundle_copy](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) & [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) are good choices as have been suggested, but...

Give [**Importer**](http://drupal.org/project/importer) a try if you want to create a new content type from external data.

1. allows you to import a dump file:

   - XLS
   - CSV
   - others
2. automatically creates a table which can then be used in Views
3. can be sued to derive a content type from that point

Comment: You should have shown a link to the Importer module, if this is what you are talking about...

Comment: OK, I know, I know, but I think you should edit the original post. :) (and write "Importer" module's name with uppercase, because this way it's not unequivocal that you're talking about a module)

Answer (score 0):

The [features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module makes this a breeze

Answer (score 0):

I have used [backup_migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module to migrate from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 and I would highly recommend this module.